# How does this replica of the getline function work?

Tags: c, pointers, stdin, getline, getchar

According to [c-for-dummies.com](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112):

> The latest and most trendy function for reading a string of text is getline(). It’s a new C library function, having appeared around 2010 or so.

> You might not have heard of the getline() function, and a few C
> programmers avoid it because it uses — brace yourself — pointers! Even
> so, it’s a good line-input function, and something you should be
> familiar with, even if you don’t plan on using it.

That page provides 2 simple examples after that description, but such examples don't explain step by step how the `getline` function actually works behind the scenes. So I seeked the code of this function in the net, and I managed to get a "**replica**" of the `getline` function called `_getline` which also uses a "**replica**" of the `getchar` function called `_getchar`, here it is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _getchar(void)
{
    int rd;
    char buff[2];

    rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 1);

    if (rd == 0)
        return (EOF);
    if (rd == -1)
        exit(99);

    return (*buff);
}

ssize_t _getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
{
    char *temp;
    const size_t n_alloc = 120;
    size_t n_read = 0;
    size_t n_realloc;
    int c;

    if (lineptr == NULL || n == NULL || stream == NULL)
        return (-1);

    if (*lineptr == NULL)
    {
        *lineptr = malloc(n_alloc);
        if (*lineptr == NULL)
            return (-1);
        *n = n_alloc;
    }
    while ((c = _getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (n_read >= *n)
        {
            n_realloc = *n + n_alloc;
            temp = realloc(*lineptr, n_realloc + 1);

            if (temp == NULL)
                return (-1);

            *lineptr = temp;
            *n = n_realloc;
        }
        n_read++;
        (*lineptr)[n_read - 1] = (char) c;

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

    }
    if (c == EOF)
        return (-1);
    (*lineptr)[n_read] = '\0';
    return ((ssize_t) n_read);
}
```

After reading the code above, I realized why it is said that there are few C programmers that avoid it, and I don't want to stay within that group so, could someone here explain how these replicas work together please?

Comment: Instead of someone annotating every line in this code: Is there a particular thing/section you do not understand if you read the code in either function?

Comment: Unrelated: I doubt that `exit(99);` is in any of the original functions and why they made it `char buff[2];` instead of a single `char` is a mystery to me.

Comment: Well, the particular section would be the ```while ((c = _getchar()) != EOF)``` loop from the ```_getline``` function. @TedLyngmo

Comment: That part keeps the `while` loop going (and reading a character, assigning it to `c`) until EOF (_End of file_) is returned by `_getchar()`. In the body of the `while` loop, `c` is then added to the buffer. if the buffer is too small to add another character, it's expanded (by calling `realloc`)

Comment: But what does ```_getchar()``` get?

Comment: It `read`s one `char` from `STDIN_FILENO` (which is the file descriptor that the `FILE*` `stdin` is using on Posix platforms).

Comment: Which specific statement of `_getchar()` don't you understand? Mainly it tries to get one character from `stdin`. However, the code is terrible.

Comment: is ```rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 1);``` only reading one char from the user's input that's within the stdin buffer or something like that?

Comment: Yes, and `return (*buff);` returns that single `char` - but it's done in a very awkward way. `unsigned char ch; if(read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) == 1) return ch; return EOF;` would be a simpler replica - and more accurate.

Comment: Note `ssize_t` is not a standard C library type.  OTOH code has `<unistd.h>`, so looks like portability is OK with that limitation.

Comment: I see, but then in which cases that single ```char``` could be ```0``` or ```-1```? I mean, which first character should exist in the stdin buffer to return ```0``` or ```-1```? @TedLyngmo

Comment: In the _real_ `getchar` the single `char` is really a single `unsigned char` _or_ `EOF` (-1) to indicate errors - which is why I suggested `unsigned char ch; if(read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) == 1) return ch; return EOF;` instead. `0` is not that special, while -1 does not exist in an `unsigned char` so that's why it's used to indicate errors / EOF.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: That `getline` replica does not even use the `stream` that you supply as an argument. The real thing will use `stream` to call `fgetc(stream)` - not `getchar()`.